# How to check the storage size of dynamodb for specific day

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Is there a way to calculate what was the storage size of the Dynamodb table for specific day. Dynamodb console only shows total storage size.

Answer (score 3):

AWS doesn't record this metric by default in CloudWatch. You would have to write a lambda function to periodically fetch this data and push it to CW manually.